# vue - moving child component code to another file

Tags: vue.js

I have a subcomponent within a file, and I want to extract it out of the file and into another file.

I'm just using vue (not cli) and php, and I don't have access to ES6, so I can't use those import statements.

```
const form = {

    ...


    components:{
        subForm:{
          /* lots of code */
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `require.js` you can just import it from the new file

```
const subForm = require('path/to/new/file);

const form = {
    components { subForm }; 
}
```

If not, you can create the component in a new file and registered in the global `Vue` instance.

```
Vue.component('subForm', {
  /* lots of code */
});
```

This will work assuming that you import the file into your HTML using a bundler or something like gulp. And that `Vue` is globally included in the DOM either through a script tag linking to a CDN or through whatever you are using to bundle the application.